# Why does my custom scrollbar box shadow styles not affect the body scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple scrollbar stylesheet that changes the scrollbar's appearance in Webkit based browsers. Here's the code:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: -1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
::-webkit-resizer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 5000px;">
  <br /><br />
  <div style="margin: auto; width: 100px; height: 500px; overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px solid black;">
    <div style="height: 1000px; padding: 24px;">
      <div>Some content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the scrollbar within the black box has the box shadow on the left side. However, the one on the body does not, even though it is the same styles being applied to both. Why does this happen?

Comment: Shadow for the scroll bar of the body shows weird effects. It shows the shadow when zoomed it and does not when I zoom out. To add shadow to the body scrollbar, just use the inset box shadow property

Comment: @weegee Could you write this out as an answer with a working example? I would accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [inset option](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp) in [`box-shadow`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp) for scroll bar shadows

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: white;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px black
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
::-webkit-resizer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
html{
  background-color:white;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 5000px;">
  <br /><br />
  <div style="margin: auto; width: 100px; height: 500px; overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px solid black;">
    <div style="height: 1000px; padding: 24px;">
      <div>Some content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```